# Your child's shorts are sagging. Do you say "Your shorts are coming out. Fix them!" or "Your shorts are coming off. Fix them!"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, idioms

We say "**You put the shorts on**" & "**You take the shorts off**"?

I am not sure if we can replace "**put**" & "**take**" with other verbs such as "**slide**", "**come**", etc.

For example, Your child's shorts are sagging.

Do you say "**Your shorts are coming off. Fix them!**"?

I am not sure if it is idiomatic to say "**Your shorts are coming out**" or "**Your shorts are coming off**"?

Comment: In the UK we would probably say, "Your shorts are falling down. Pull them up." Or just, "Pull your shorts up."

Comment: We most definitely do not say "your shorts are coming out". We say: Your shorts are sliding down or have slid down. Pull them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right choice is

> Your shorts are coming off.

If you said, 'Your shorts are coming out' it would mean that the shorts are inside of something, like a box, a suitcase or a dryer.

If you know what the person understands by 'fixing' their shorts, you can say

> Your shorts are coming off. Fix them!

but this is very direct and implies a judgement that there's something wrong with the shorts the way they are, which could prompt a negative reaction by the person you're speaking to.

You could say

> You slide the shorts on.
>   You slide the shorts off.
>   Your shorts are sliding off.

This has a slightly more sensual or motive connotation.